# What’s the probability that a random walk on the Gaussian integers reaches a prime before a composite?

Tags: prime-numbers, markov-chains, expected-value, random-walk, gaussian-integers

I just learned how useful the [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) $\mathbb Z[\mathrm i]$ are for solving problems in $\mathbb Z$ (much like $\mathbb C$ is useful for solving problems in $\mathbb R$), and I was a bit surprised that I hadn’t come across them more often on this site. So I thought I’d ask a fun question about them that might get others interested in them. If you want to learn more about the Gaussian integers, I’d recommend [these notes by Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/Zinotes.pdf).

Here are the first few Gaussian integers (“first” in the sense of the norm $N(a+b\mathrm i)=a^2+b^2)$:

\begin{array}{cc}
&&
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px blue]{-1+3\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{3\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px blue]{1+3\mathrm i}
\\
&
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px blue]{-2+2\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{-1+2\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px blue]{2\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{1+2\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px blue]{2+2\mathrm i}
\\
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px blue]{-3+\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{-2+\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{-1+\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:red;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px red]{\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{1+\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{2+\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px blue]{3+\mathrm i}
\\
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{-3}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px blue]{-2}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:red;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px red]{-1}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:black;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px black]{0}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:red;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px red]{1}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px blue]{2}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{3}
\\
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px blue]{-3-\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{-2-\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{-1-\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:red;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px red]{-\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{1-\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{2-\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px blue]{3-\mathrm i}
\\
&
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px blue]{-2-2\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{-1-2\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px blue]{-2\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{1-2\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px blue]{2-2\mathrm i}
\\
&&
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px blue]{-1-3\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:green;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px green]{-3\mathrm i}
&
\bbox[2pt,color:blue;border-radius:32px;box-shadow:4px 4px 4px blue]{1-3\mathrm i}
\end{array}

Zero is black, units are red, primes are green and composites are blue. (Fun fact: The first prime in $\mathbb Z$, $2$, is the first composite in $\mathbb Z[\mathrm i]$.)

Consider a simple symmetric random walk on the Gaussian integers, starting at zero.

a) What’s the probability that it reaches a prime before it reaches a composite?

b) What’s the expected time to reach a prime?

c) What’s the expected time to reach a composite?

(Note that only the Gaussian integers depicted above are needed to answers these questions.)

Answer (score 4):

a) This one’s straightforward: Each unit has two prime neighbours and one composite neighbour, so the probability to reach a prime first is $\frac23$.

b) There are three possible states before a prime is reached: The associates of $0$, $1$ and $2$, respectively. The expected times $E_k$ for reaching a prime from state $k$ satisfy

\begin{eqnarray}
E_0&=&1+E_1\;,\\
E_1&=&1+\frac14E_0+\frac14E_2\;,\\
E_2&=&1+\frac14E_1\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Substituting the first and third equations into the second yields $E_1=\frac{24}{11}$, and substituting that into the first equation yields
$E_0=\frac{35}{11}=3.\overline{18}$.

c) This one’s a bit more complicated. There are $4$ possible states before a composite is reached: the associates of $0$, $1$, $1+\mathrm i$ and $2+\mathrm i$, respectively. The expected times $E_k$ for reaching a prime from state $k$ satisfy

\begin{eqnarray}
E_0&=&1+E_1\;,\\
E_1&=&1+\frac14E_0+\frac12E_{1+\mathrm i}\;,\\
E_{1+\mathrm i}&=&1+\frac12E_1+\frac12E_{2+\mathrm i}\;,\\
E_{2+\mathrm i}&=&1+\frac14E_{1+\mathrm i}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Substituting from the bottom up yields $E_{1+\mathrm i}=\frac{12}7+\frac47E_1$, then $E_1=\frac{13}5+\frac7{20}E_0$, and then $E_0=\frac{72}{13}\approx5.54$, nearly twice as long as it takes to reach a prime.